# How do I move a part of a picture with tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I'm drawing a picture by using `tikzpicture`. Suppose the picture is made by many objects. At the end of my work I realize that I need to move only one of these objects, say shift right by 1 unit. Clearly I can change all coordinates by (a,b) --> (a+1,b). Clearly this is not a good solution.

In the classical ambient picture there is the command `\put(x,y){...}` that allow you to move an entire sub-part of a picture.

Is there anything similar in the ambient `tikzpicture`? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a common transformation to several objects by placing them in a scope.
Example from the [TikZ/pgf Manual (section 25.3)](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
        \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
        \draw[yshift=1cm] [blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
        \draw[rotate=30] [orange] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `scope` with the `shift` option, which takes an arbitrary shift vector.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
     \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`shift` has the advantage of being in the same way affected by redefining `x` and `y` units as the other coordinates, whereas `xshift` and `yshift` will remain unaffected. Compare

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
     \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm]
     \draw[fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm] % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
     \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm]
     \draw[fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice to know that I can use the option shift with an arbitrary verctor

Comment: @user126154 `xshift=1cm` and `shift={(1,0)}` are not equivalent, see my post. `xshift` shifts by 1cm, whereas `shift` shifts by 1 unit, which needn't be the same. The correct choice depends on what you want to achieve.